# VSTS : Linking Tasks as child to Scenario using Rest API

Tags: c#, json, azure-devops-rest-api

I have created Scenario and tasks in `VSTS` using Rest API. Now i am trying to link the tasks to that particular scenario using Rest API. I have seen some code logics where they are using `System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward` but i am not sure how i can accommodate that in my code. Can anyone please help me in this ?

I have created tasks and scenario using `JsonPatchDocument` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer for the ask :

```
                document.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Path = "/relations/-",
                    Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
                    Value = new
                    {
                        rel = "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
                        url = collectionUri + "/_apis/wit/workItems/" + porWorkItemID.ToString(),
                        attributes = new
                        {
                            comment = "Making a new link for the dependency"
                        }
                    }
                    });
```